# How to start tomcat 5.5 service in windows XP

Tags: tomcat5.5

I downloaded tomcat 5.5 service installer. now please let me know how to start the tomcat service in windows XP machine? please help me.

Answer (score 2):

if you installed the zip file (unzip the file) then you need to execute the `startup.bat` file in the bin folder of tomcat.

if you installed the exe version of tomcat then you need to go to Services > Apache Tomcat 5.5 & click on start.

services window can be opened by typing `services.msc` in the run dialog or via computer management (`compmgmt.msc`)..

when you install tomcat you'll also get a status monitor you can use this to start/stop the tomcat service.